# Get in Random Order Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have made a query about taking 40 question of 7215 in total with this code,

```
$questions = Question::where([
    'visible' => 'yes',
    'deleted' => 'no'
])
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->take(40)
    ->get();
```

but in some cases I get the same question more than 1 time in this query, is there any way to take 1 question only once?

Comment: replace get with first() if you want to take one question at a time

Comment: @RahulMeshram i need to get 40 different questions in this query every time I execute it

Comment: @User154584 : I think you can try distinct() after take(40)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your query with distinct, not sure if it works with inRandomOrder:

```
$questions = Question::where([
'visible' => 'yes',
'deleted' => 'no'
])
->inRandomOrder()
->take(40)
->distinct()
->get();
```